How to customize done-color, active-color, and inactive-color in q-stepper component in Quasar?
I am working with the q-stepper component in Quasar and would like to customize the colors for each state of the steps: done-color, active-color, and inactive-color.
I’ve encountered this issue not only with q-stepper but also with several other components in Quasar, where I’m unable to apply custom colors.
Here is my current code:
<q-stepper
ref="stepperRef"
v-model="step"
animated
done-color="var(--theme-sea-green-400)"
active-color="var(--theme-primary)"
inactive-color="warning-400"
class="q-ma-xs q-pa-sm"
style="background-color: var(--theme-2)">

<q-step
    :name="1"
    :title="$t('asset_managment.meter_list.meter_transfer_dialog.select_source_modem')"
    icon="router"
    class="flex"
    :done="step > 1"/>
</q-stepper>

I tried using some CSS classes and CSS variables but haven't managed to achieve the result I need. I want each state (done, active, and inactive) to have a custom color.My main goal, as shown in the code, is to use done-color, active-color, and inactive-color with custom SCSS colors.
How can I apply custom colors for each step state in q-stepper?

don't use var.  define custom classes for CSS colors.  see the quasar docs, then the colors can be provided to the props using string names.  e.g. defining .text-sea-green-400 { #3ea99f } will allow done-color="sea-green-400"

The issue I'm facing is that I want to use SCSS variables to assign one color for light mode and a different color for dark mode in my web application.

you still can create classes for light/dark mode.  the classes can use var, the props in the template code can not.  see this answer for more specific guidance.
